# How can I hide a code block in the latex output?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have the following line at the start of an org file to configure it to use listings for code blocks.

```
#+name: setup-listings
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results silent :export none
  (setq org-latex-listings 't)
  (require 'ox-latex)
  (add-to-list 'org-latex-packages-alist '("" "listings"))
  (add-to-list 'org-latex-packages-alist '("" "color"))
#+end_src
#+call: setup-listings()
```

When I export this to a latex document the listings package gets set up correctly. But this block is also put in the latex document. What do I need to do so that this one specific block is not included into the output?

Comment: `export` -> `exports`. Note the "s".

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the `noexport` tag.  Create a heading containing the source block, then go to a heading and type <kbd>C-c C-q</kbd> and enter `:noexport:`.  This will no longer be listed in the export.

If you just want to hide the source block, you may be able to add a tag for just the source block, but I haven't tried it.